# Decreasing plot height for ax.annotate in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to print the text ("KL distance ...") under only right plot. The right plot can be shorter and the text can be printed in many lines. Is there a way to frame and print it out under the right plot?

[image]

Now I'm using ax.annotate in Matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 3), (0, 2), rowspan=1)
ax2.plot(tracking)
track_label = "KL distance : ", tracking
ax2.annotate(track_label, xy=(0.5, 0),
        xycoords=('axes fraction', 'figure fraction'),
        xytext=(0, 10),  
        textcoords='offset points',
        size=7,ha='center', va='bottom')
```

Comment: Hey, please check if my answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44037857/5103802) can answer you. It's also about text under subplots.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "textbox" or similar in matplotlib. You may introduce linebreaks in the text yourself or you can let the text wrap at the figure boundaries as shown in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/autowrap_demo.html).

To get the text to align to the right subplot you can place it in axes coordinates,

```
ax2.text(0,-0.1, track_label, ha="left", wrap=True)
```